# Неправильно отображается кнопка в выпадающем списке элемента select в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ubuntu, bootstrap, firefox

На ubuntu 17 в firefox не правильно отображаются бустраповские кнопочки выпадающего списка см рисунок (слева bootstrap, справа обычные html) они так выглядят на двух компах где стоит ubuntu 17.10 и firefox последней версии, как можно это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чтобы править нажмите в вопросе править, далее нажмите ctrl+m и вставляйте ваш код [mcve]

Comment: Если так сильно волнует вопрос, а подходящего ответа так и нет, то посмотрите [как правильно задавать хорошие вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), тк у вас ни версии бутстрапа, ни примера, а при попытках воспроизвести то, что вы описываете словами никаких ошибок не возникает. Очень скудно со входящими данными.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы добавили свои стили: ограничение на ширину например, свои паддинги и пр. Посмотрите в отладчике, что перекрывает стили бустрапа. **Без вашего минимального воспроизводимого примера сложно сказать**. Тк на ubuntu в firefox в примере из документации [стрелка показывается и работает](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#selects), но выглядит она нативно (*скрин с ubuntu*):

[image: ubuntu в firefox стрелка]

Используйте новый поддерживаемый 4ый бутстап, на днях наконец-то вышел релиз после альфы и беты. В нем селекты(и не только селекты) везде [показываются одинаково](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#custom-select).

---

UPD Подозреваю, что у вас третий бутсрап (!трех летней давности), а ос у вас бета у которой полноценный релиз будет только через 2! месяца текущего года, и сами разработчики рекомендуют 16 версию. Ошибку либо еще не пофиксили, или уже трогать не будут по причине перехода на 4ый бустрап. Попробуйте [написать на гитхаб разработчикам бутсрапа](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues). Возможно там вам что-то посоветуют.